# Ionic playing media after stop

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, media

I try to work in Ionic1 and have an confussing issue here:

I want to play a media (mp3 e.g.) direkt after an another one stopped. 
Speaking: Have list of songs. If one is running - click an another one - then stop the current and start the new one...

But I missed something... 
Here is the code:

Thanks in advance for any hints.

! sound is just a object with title, url and sta for status. !

```
    var currentSound, currentMedia;
    $scope.play = function(sound) {

    if(currentMedia && currentSound && currentSound.sta == 1){
      currentMedia.stop();
      currentSound.sta = 0;

      if(sound.title === currentSound.title) return;
    }

    var mediaUrl = sound.url;
    if(device.platform.indexOf("iOS") >= 0) {
      mediaUrl = "../Library/NoCloud/" + mediaUrl.split("/").pop();
    }

    currentSound = sound;
    currentMedia = new Media(mediaUrl,
        function() {
          currentMedia.release();
          currentSound.sta = 0;
        }, function(err) {
          console.log("media err", err);
        }, function (sta) {
          if(sta == Media.MEDIA_RUNNING)
          {
            currentSound.sta = 1;
          }
          else
          {
            currentSound.sta = 0;
          }
        });

    currentMedia.play();
    currentSound.sta = 1;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK - I found a solution... even if I dont understand it. (I am open for your wisdom)

Solution: just call the function recursivly in case of stop&start a media.

var currentSound, currentMedia;
  $scope.play = function(sound) {

```
if(currentMedia && currentSound && currentSound.sta == 1){
  currentMedia.stop();
  currentSound.sta = 0;

  if(sound.title === currentSound.title)
  {
    return;
  }
  else
  {
    $scope.play(sound);
  }
}

var mediaUrl = sound.url;
if(device.platform.indexOf("iOS") >= 0) {
  mediaUrl = "../Library/NoCloud/" + mediaUrl.split("/").pop();
}

currentSound = sound;
currentMedia = new Media(mediaUrl,
    function() {
      currentMedia.release();
      currentSound.sta = 0;

    }, function(err) {
      console.log("media err", err);

    }, function (sta) {

      if(sta == Media.MEDIA_RUNNING)
      {
        currentSound.sta = 1;
      }
      else
      {
        currentSound.sta = 0;
      }
    });

currentMedia.play();
currentSound.sta = 1;
```

}